# How to select SQL Server row values as columns (Dynamic Pivot)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have one table where we are collecting status data from different sensors. For reporting purposes I would need to group information for each sensor (SGUID) to one row. Each sensor is sending reader (RGUID) and value for reader (VAL).

Source table:
[image: Source table]

Goal result:
[image: Goal result]

I have heard about pivot's but don't know how to use those in this kind of case.

Comment: Do you know the rguids at develop time? Means: Are you able to hardcode them into a query or do you need to retrieve the values dynamically?

Comment: This is most likely will be dynamic and will require `Dynamic Pivot`.

Probably duplicate for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a dynamic pivot using some dynamic T-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE #VALS (
    VALS NVARCHAR(4000)
)

INSERT INTO #VALS
SELECT DISTINCT RGUID
FROM [TABLE]

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @VALS NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @VALS = COALESCE(@VALS+', ','') + '[' + VALS + ']' FROM #VALS

SET @SQL = '
SELECT SGUID, '+@VALS+'
FROM [TABLE]
PIVOT(MAX(VAL) FOR RGUID IN ('+@VALS+')) PIV'
PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

The `PRINT` will show you the constructed query. From there you can debug any issues quite simply. The idea is fairly simple, I've created a working fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d2b391/1).